# Running time of binary search

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, sorting

Assume I have regular binary search, but I change the `mid` to `2/3*(min+max)`.
Will the running time change, or remain (`log(n)`)?

I got `c1+c2*log(n)/log(3/2)`.

Comment: Hope you know that the mid is index ... and not the element it self in binary search ! ...

Comment: Admittedly had to do some back of the napkin work to make sure this wouldn't affect the correctness.

Comment: just use log(a)/log(b). The performance will reduce. the time complexity will be O(log(n))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll still be log(n).  You'll have a different log base (3/2 instead of 2), but changing a log base is the same as multiplying by a constant.